# Java-config counterpart of wss:binding?

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws

Ok, so here's something I've been googling for for hours with no success... Finally i can only hope some Spring-magician reads and answers this question. :)

I'm upgrading an old web application (Spring 2.x-based) to Spring 4.2.x and while adding new features I've decided to completely move away from XML-based config. (Again: i don't want to have any Spring XML files in the project!)

I've converted pretty much everything, but the last thing i can't resolve is finding the correct Java-config counterpart of:

```
<ws:service id="MySoapService" bean="#ServiceImpl" />
<wss:binding service="#MySoapService" url="/1.0/soap" />
```

ws/wss namespaces come from:

```
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
```

So what i'm trying to do is exporting `@WebService` annotated classes, but with Java-config instead of XML.

Additional infos:

- I've tried using `SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter`, but that one leaves me with a "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind", regardless of what port i'm using...
- The application has two servlets: one is a normal Spring MVC Dispatcher for the new REST API and another `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet` which should make the above mentioned JAX-WS service available.
- I'm trying to resolve things with pure JAX-WS RI, no CXF or any other library. The application is huge enough already... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by injecting your endpoint and the following helper method (note that my approach uses a base class `BaseEndpoint` for each endpoint):

```
@Configuration
public WebserviceConfiguration {

    @Inject
    private FooEndpoint fooEndpoint;

    @Bean    
    public SpringBinding fooEndpoint() throws Exception {
        return bind(fooEndpoint, "ws/bar");
    }

    private SpringBinding bind(BaseEndpoint endpoint, String url) throws Exception {
        SpringService springService = new SpringService();
        springService.setBean(endpoint);
        SpringBinding binding = new SpringBinding();
        binding.setService(springService.getObject());
        binding.setUrl(url);
        return binding;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks pretty solid. Will try this and if works, I'll change the accepted answer to this. (If i can... SO newbie here)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there's no solution (yet?) - after quite a few more hours of googling around, i've found only this ticket:

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS_COMMONS-134

Looking at its date and status (and by noting the fact that devs didn't even respond to it, even a year has passed), i assume it's safe to state that JAX-WS Commons spring integration will not support Java config in the foreseeable future.